# Hibernate create tables in db from inheritors

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, jpa

Hello Can you say how to create tables in DB from iheritors (not create one table for base class with inheritors with descriminators)?
for example:
I have base abstract class:

```
public abstract class Person
{
      public string Name;

}
```

and some inheritors like:

```
 public class Student : Person 

    public string University;

 }

 public class Driver : Person 
 {
    public string CarName;

 }
```

I need in DataBase Tables:
Student:
-id
-Name
-University

and Driver:
-id
-Name:
-CarName

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be talking about "table per concrete subclass". This approach doesn't need a discriminator, but requires column-names be common between the separate tables (as internally, it fetchs via a UNION).

See:    http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass

I will note that your "Person, Driver, Student" example is likely an incorrect design -- as the same person can be *both* a Driver and a Student.

I assume you want to keep the STUDENT and DRIVER table design, which is simple, and that you don't really want a unified role-based system where Person -> Driver and Person -> Student are represented as relationships.

Following that assumption, you could either:

1. Remove the common superclass Person from Hibernate mappings altogether -- since it won't really correct to retrieve "all People" by it, since people who are both Drivers and Students will be duplicated;  and/or
2. Replace the common superclass 'Person' with an interface 'IPersonInfo', not mapped by Hibernate;  or,
3. Weaken the definition of superclass 'Person' & rename it to 'PersonInfo', so it no longer implies identity (since each unique record is no longer guaranteed to be a single unique person).

*If this isn't a toy design & you wanted to accurately model this or a more extensive system, you'd have to design the model properly:*

4)    Separate 'Person' entity from the *Roles* they can have. Student, Driver etc then descend from *Role* (probably an abstract class, so it can be mapped by Hibernate). Roles are then associated/related from Person, either by several 0..1 or as a big bag of Roles.

Comment: thanks:) but if in the class Person I will immplement some base methods for all clasess, this aproach will not be very good

Comment: You can implement common methods in PersonInfo, and this approach is both correct and good. Your approach would be wrong since someone who is both a Driver and a Student, would have to be two separate people!  *Wrong.*